# Angular - Multiple fields in ng-messages

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

I'm using `ng-messages` and want to know if its possible to check across multiple fields in one block of code rather than having to repeat:

So I have:
(note `checkCustom` is a custom directive I have wrote)

```
<div ng-messages="registrationForm.field1.$error" ng-if="registrationFormValid">
    <span ng-message="required">please enter field 1</span>
    <span ng-message="checkCustom">please check custom value</span>
</div>
```

and

```
<div ng-messages="registrationForm.field2.$error" ng-if="registrationFormValid">
    <span ng-message="required">please enter field 1</span>
    <span ng-message="checkCustom">please check custom value</span>
</div>
```

However I'd much rather something like:

```
<div ng-messages="registrationForm.field1.$error || registrationForm.field2.$error" ng-if="registrationFormValid">
    <span ng-message="required">please enter field 1</span>
    <span ng-message="checkCustom">please check custom value</span>
</div>
```

Is something like this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Partially solved - can use the syntax `ng-messages="{ checkCustom: !main.field1 || !main.field2}"` and `ng-messages="{ required: !main.field1 || !main.field2}"`

Answer (score 4):

[A form's controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) has a handy property called `$error`. This is an object hash, **containing references to controls or forms with failing validators**, where its keys are the error names (e.g. `email`, `required`, `minlength`, etc) and their values are arrays of controls or forms that have a failing validator for given error name - [source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$error).

This means that we can **globaly check for an error inside a form** just by examining if this `$error` object **contains a specific key name**.

Have a look at this example:

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMessages']);
```

```css
[ng-cloak] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak>
  <form name="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h3>Validation messages:</h3>

      <div ng-messages="myForm.$error" multiple>
        <div ng-message="required" class="alert alert-danger">There's at least one <strong>required</strong> field</div>
        <div ng-message="minlength" class="alert alert-danger">There's at least one field which doesn't fulfill the <strong>minlength</strong> condition</div>
        <div ng-message="email" class="alert alert-danger">The form contains an invalid <strong>email</strong> input</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Required Input 1</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="myModel1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Required Input 2</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="myModel2" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Required Input 3 which has min-length="3"</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="myModel3" required ng-minlength="3">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Required Input 4 which is type="email"</label>
      <input type="email" ng-model="myModel4" required>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Excellent yet underrated answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add same messages in all the blocks and add it in a single place you can do something like this:

1. Add all the messages in a file

   `<!-- remote file: error-messages.html --><div ng-message="required">please enter field 1</div>
   <div ng-message="checkCustom">please check custom value</div>`
2. Just include that file where ever you want.

   `<div ng-messages="registrationForm.field1.$error" ng-messages-include="error-messages.html">
   </div>`

So the code is reused. For a different error message override that message inside the block.

For more information check this amazing [blog post](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/05/how-to-use-ngmessages-in-angularjs.html).
I don't think you can add two fields in a single ng-messages block.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
<div ng-if="registrationForm.field1.$error.required || registrationForm.field2.$error.required">
<span class="required">please enter field 1</span>
</div>
```